# Find Codeception first elements with more than one CSS class with same name

Tags: css-selectors, functional-testing, codeception, acceptance-testing, acceptance

I have something like the following markup:

```html
<div class="test">
  <div class="test2">test</div>
  <div class="test2">test2</div>
  <div class="test2">test3</div>
  <div class="test2">test4</div>
 </div
```

I want to click the first test2 class

Comment: You would only be able to target the last child of .test if you are checking all the other children, you can't search UP the DOM without using :has()

Answer (score 1):

Check this cheatsheet, it explains how to get the first element of an html tag : https://devhints.io/xpath

```php
$I->click('(//div[@class="test2"])[1]');
```

This code should work, just try it here : https://extendsclass.com/xpath-tester.html

Answer (score 0):

Maybe something like this
.test .test2:nth-child(1)

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).